# Change div background image, js works in chrome but not ie or firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Basically I want the user to be able to click and change the background, and for there to be multiple backgrounds, for a specific div.

This works perfectly in Google Chrome but not in IE or Firefox.

HTML:

```
<div id="palette">
<div class="lightblue"></div>
<div class="gold"></div>
<div class="aqua"></div>
</div>

<div id="primary">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#palette {
border: 2px solid white;
width: 25px;
}

#palette div {
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}

.lightblue { 
background: lightblue url(http://www.textureking.com/content/img/stock/big/DSC_4279.JPG); 
}

.gold { 
background: gold url(http://www.textureking.com/content/img/stock/big/DSC_4287.JPG); 
}

 .aqua { 
background: aqua url(http://www.textureking.com/content/img/stock/big/DSC_4274.JPG);
```

}

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// attach onclick event to your palette colors
$('#palette div').on('click', function() {
    // get background of selected palette color
    var bg = $(this).css('background');
    // change the background of the body
    $('#primary').css({ 'background': bg });
}); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KNutQ/1/

It's not showing any errors and other javascripts run, so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

If it's easy to fix please leave an answer, if not I will try it this way: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_backgroundimage

Comment: Hmm perhaps a cookie could be created to remember the background they chose?

Answer (score 0):

According to the CSS specification getting the computed style of a shorthand should not return anything. You need to list out the individual properties as I've done below.

Perhaps the CSS spec or Chrome will change in the future but at the moment Firefox and IE's behaviour is correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // attach onclick event to your palette colors
    $('#palette div').on('click', function() {
        // get background of selected palette color
        var backgrounds = $(this).css(['background-color','background-image', 'background-repeat', 'background-attachment', 'background-position']);
         // change the background of the body
        $('body').css(backgrounds);
    }); 
});
```